# Simple georeferenced 3D data format for building models

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, 3d, gml

I am looking for a simple georeferenced 3D-data format to store very simple building models. Each building should be represented as a number of poylgons, semantics do not matter. It would be ideal if this format is readable via ArcGIS, but that is not an absolute requirement.

I know there is GML/CityGML but I am looking for something simpler that ideally has either a JSON or XML serialization.

Comment: ArcGIS no - OpenSource yes https://github.com/madeincluj/3d-buildings GeoJSON with support for 3D

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a XML based 3D model for buildings you may want to look at KML format. If you need the model to hold textures, then you will not be able to use KML, and will have to use a KMZ. SketchUp can hold textures and geographic coordinates, but it is not XML based.