# BlenderGIS: georeferencing and exporting 3d model?

Tags: georeferencing, 3d, blendergis

I can add a georeferenced basemap using BlenderGIS and overlay my 3d model on this basemap.

I want to export this 3D model as a georeferenced file, but only see a shapefile export option (which cannot store textures).

How do I export a 3D georeferenced model using BlenderGIS?

Comment: This may be better suited to https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think the first question is: what format do you want to export to? Maybe these other questions can help:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99712/listing-file-formats-to-represent-georeferenced-3d-data
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96001/simple-georeferenced-3d-data-format-for-building-models

Comment: I need it to go to ArcGIS, so ESRI multipatch. I use the import 3D files tool in ArcGIS Pro... georeferencing there is a pain!